# PostgreSQL: Warning: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, warnings

Using **PostgreSQL** when I *connect* to a db using `\c testdb` inside PostgreSQL Database SQL Prompt. I successfully connect to the db but getting the following warning:

```
postgres-# \c testdb
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
You are now connected to database "testdb" as user "postgres".
testdb-#
```

What does this warning mean? How to resolve it?

Comment: @jww could you post a link here of the guidelines for stackoverflow vs. super user vs. database admins?

Answer (score 52):

From the [psql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html):

> psql is built as a "console application". Since the Windows console
>   windows use a different encoding than the rest of the system, you must
>   take special care when using 8-bit characters within psql. If psql
>   detects a problematic console code page, it will warn you at startup.
>
> To change the console code page, two things are necessary: 
>   Set the code page by entering cmd.exe /c chcp 1252. (1252 is a code
>   page that is appropriate for German; replace it with your value.) If
>   you are using Cygwin, you can put this command in /etc/profile.

So to remove that warning you need to execute `chcp 1252` before you enter`psql`. Using `chcp` without parameters gives you the current codepage.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I tried executing the code 1252 but error still persist. 

In your solution, you mentioned 2 things to do but described only 1. Could you please explain the second thing to do

Comment: @Abhishek I'm not sure what you're asking. `chcp` shows the current encoding (aka code page). `chcp 1252` changes the encoding to `Latin 1 / Western European`, which is used for German. More details on Windows code pages see wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page

Comment: what's the 2nd thing?

Comment: I assume this is the "Notes for Windows Users" referenced in the warning: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html (toward bottom of page)

Comment: It's helpful to add `chcp 1252` to the psql bat file itself, which on my machine is located at "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\scripts\runpsql.bat".

Comment: This one helped me change it more widely on windows although someone reported issue with some program https://superuser.com/a/1435645/1064813

Comment: @Abhishek, fwiw, dvdgsng provided an excerpt from the psql docs, but not all of it. It is missing the second instruction which is Set the console font to Lucida Console, because the raster font does not work with the ANSI code page. You can find it here: https:/postgresql.org/docs/14/app-psql.html. I am not sure though if this second step solves any problems you may encounter. The simplest way I could resolve the issue is by creating a simple batch script something like this: ```chcp 1252;  psql -U postgres```

Answer (score 26):

The default codepage for CMD.exe is different than the default for postgres... To change for CMD.exe using the REGISTRY try this:

1. Start -> Run -> regedit
2. Go to [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
3. Add new string value named "Autorun" with value "chcp 1252"

Then reopen CMD.exe

Comment: I know this is over 2 years old, but since it has no accepted answer, I would like to say that this worked for me.

Comment: It works even if one (me) uses psql command line tool installed with the postgres run directly (my Command Prompt doesn't recognise psql command because I don't put it in the path and I prefer it this way). It changes the code page of the prompt that I run from the tool.

Comment: The encoding needed to work with the Postgres depends on the database encoding though, and that needs to be set in a code page of a specific Command Prompt where the Postgres is running if it is different than the globally set code page for the Console (cmd.exe/Command Prompt) which can be set by this method.

Answer (score 13):

To make it even  more obvious, the file to which @user3423801 is adding the line

```
cmd.exe /c chcp 1252
```

is in the `scripts` directory where you installed Postgre.

For example, in my case it is

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\scripts\runpsql.bat
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. It works when I open the terminal through the batch file. But when I use `sql` the warning still pops up.

Answer (score 8):

Please don't assume that Unix fixes work for Windows Users.  For Windows 10, and PostgreSQL 12, combining the answers by "user3423801" and "numbers longer" worked for me.  (The Windows Registry hack would not work.  I did not try rebooting yet.)  It is better to fix it in the PSQL startup script anyway.

The file location `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\scripts` contains the file `runpsql.bat`, into which you must insert the `cmd.exe /c chcp 1252 command` in the right location. So the top of your edited file should look like the 5 or 6 lines below.

```
@echo off

REM Copyright (c) 2012-2014, EnterpriseDB Corporation.  All rights reserved

REM PostgreSQL server psql runner script for Windows

cmd.exe /c chcp 1252

SET server=localhost
SET /P server="Server [%server%]: "
```

Answer (score 7):

Open cmd.exe and run `regedit`.

Go to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor`

New a string value named: `Autorun` and change the value to be `chcp 1252`

Done.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30100565/8396969

Answer (score 4):

The answer of dvdgsng is correct but with code example is more obviously.

```
@echo off

REM Copyright (c) 2012-2014, EnterpriseDB Corporation.  All rights reserved

REM PostgreSQL server psql runner script for Windows

cmd.exe /c chcp 1252

SET server=localhost
SET /P server="Server [%server%]: "
```

Answer (score 4):

Or you can simply type `cmd.exe /c chcp 1252` in the Command Prompt window.

Comment: If what the OP needs is the 1252 code page. The encoding needed depends on the database encoding. The code page number of more universal utf-8 encoding 65001.

Answer (score 3):

you just go to the power-shell or cmd.exe and type the command `chcp 1252` or whatever the page number it wants "the one that is the windows code page". If the problem still persists, just open the console properties 'By clicking the power shell icon on the top left of the console window and choosing properties from the drop-down menu' and change the font to "Lucida Console". It worked for me, But you have to open power-shell as an Administrator.

Answer (score 2):

The answers above are okay, but don't mention anywhere that Windows 1252 encoding is good for English language versions of Windows AND the other Western European Languages.  This completes the answer for those people who may get confused about the aforementioned application to German language encoding.  Yes it works for English without umlauts and other special characters needed for German, Spanish, French, Italian, Romanian, Hungarian, etc.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252

What is Windows 1252 encoding?

Windows-1252 or CP-1252 (code page 1252) is a single-byte character encoding of the Latin alphabet, used by default in the legacy components of Microsoft Windows for English and some other Western languages (other languages use different default encodings).

Answer (score 1):

After much digging for an answer that made sense to me, I found this [help email chain](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/549275CC.4010607%40gmail.com) at the PostgreSQL site which basically says to run `chcp 1252` from inside an open command window.
I was then able to run my PostgreSQL commands without the code warning.

NOTE: this change does not persist so you have to run it every time you open a new command window where you plan to use PostgreSQL commands.

Answer (score 1):

For **Postgres 11**

> "WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page
>   (1252)
>            8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
>            page "Notes for Windows users" for details."

**If you aren't an administrator on your machine**
Add a line "chcp 1252" to the pg_env.bat script found in the base directory of your postgres installation.'
    i.e. "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11" 
**If you are and Administrator on your machine**
you can modify the registry to run the line everytime you run "cmd.exe" as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out how to set it for Cygwin globally. This seemed to work though in my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd.exe /c chcp 1252 && psql -h myserver.postgres.database.azure.com -U myuser@prod-au -d mydatabase
```

Comment: i just pasted **cmd.exe /c chcp 1252** into my command prompt on windows 10 and it worked. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the command prompt terminal just type in `chcp 1252`; no need to open any file or go to any file path

Example:

```
C:\Users\dsmith> chcp 1252
```

After that, when you log in to `psql` from this cmd terminal, you will not see the problem of console code warning

Answer (score 0):

Basically, set your console application encoding from 8-bit to <s>utf-8</s> Windows 1252.

For **git bash** users
run the command `chcp.com 1252` before running postgres

chcp is a windows console command, so to execute it on git bash you might need to add **`.com`**

> git bash can't extend chcp to a full executable on its own, so you need to type the full command.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29279304/git-bash-chcp-windows7-encoding-issue)

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why do you think that this helps?

Comment: codepage 1252 is not utf8. if it was, I would not get utf8 errors ... its basically an iso encoding.

Answer (score 0):

1. On the terminal screen go to the following directory;

```
    C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin
```

note: whichever database version you are using, go to the **bin folder** of the db version file.

2. Before creating a user or accessing the database user, you must write the following code;

```
    cmd.exe /c chcp 1252
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows, edit `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\xx\scripts\runpsql.bat`

If you do not have write access, you may edit the file via an administrator command prompt. You may also go into the file's properties and edit the Security Permissions to include write access for your user/group.

Add the following on its own line before the SET variables: `chcp <console_code>`

Replace `<console_code>` with the code given to you by the psql shell warning.

Finally right click the very top of your console, go into the properties, and change the font to **Lucida Console**. This is a font which will work correctly with the code page.

More information can be found here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/app-psql.html

Answer (score 0):

Im currently using psql 15.2 and I use it with the git bash terminal.

To be able to use it from anywhere I first added `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin` to my system environment variables. Then I noticed when executing the command `psql`, I recieved the same error as shown in this thread.

The solution I came up with is:

I added the following lines to my `.bash_profile` file (C:\Users<user>.bash_profile)

```
# psql conf

chcp.com 1252 >/dev/null
alias psql='psql.exe'

# end of psql conf
```

Notice that when running the command `chcp` from the git bash terminal doesn't work, it works when you run `chcp.com`.

And after running `chcp.com 1252`, when you run `psql -U <username>` and logging to an account, the error shows up again. Just when you run `psql.exe -U <username>` the error doesn't show anymore. That's why I added the alias.

If anyone knows why in this case running `psql` is different than running `psql.exe`, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users:

I couldn't change the `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\xx\scripts\runpsql.bat` file because I don't have admin rights (work computer). So instead I opened the psql start up file (`%appdata%\postgresql\psqlrc.conf`, if it's not there you can just create one) and simply added `\! chcp 1252`. Restarted the server and works like a charm.