# Git bash chcp windows7 encoding issue

Tags: ruby, git, bash

Guys How I can change the encoding  on Git bash command screen ?

I'm using windows 7 and when I'm trying to install any Ruby gem I usually got this issue

```
$ gem install libv8 -- --with-system-v8
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
    unknown encoding name - CP720
```

so when I try to use the command `chcp 1252` it's gives me the error

```
$ chcp 1252
sh.exe": chcp: command not found
```

So how I can change the encoding on the git bash command screen ??

Answer (score 18):

This is probably way too late, but anyway you need to use :

`chcp.com 1252`

because git bash can't extend `chcp` to a full executable on its own, so you need to type the full command.