# Python str vs unicode on Windows, Python 2.7, why does 'á' become '\xa0'

Tags: python, windows, encoding

**Background**

I'm using a Windows machine. I know Python 2.* is not supported anymore, but I'm still learning Python 2.7.16. I also have Python 3.7.1. I know in Python 3.* ["`unicode` was renamed to `str`"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18034409/1175496)

I use Git Bash as my main shell.

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034272/python-str-vs-unicode-types). I feel like I understand the difference between Unicode (code points) and encodings (different encoding systems; bytes).

**Question**

- When I evaluate `'á'`, I expect to get `'\xc3\xa1'` [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49138962/1175496)
- When I evaluate `len('á')`, I expect to get `2`, [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18034409/1175496)

But I don't get expected results.
When running git bash C:\Python27\python.exe...:

```
Python 2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  4 2019, 01:37:19) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

>>> 'á'
'\xa0'
#'\xc3\xa1' expected

>>> len('á') 
1
#2 expected

# one more for reference:
>>> 'à'
'\x85'
#'\xc3\xa0' expected
```

Can you help me understand why I get the output shown above?

**Specifically why does `'á'` become `'\xa0'`?**

**What I tried**

I can use `unicode` object to get the results I expect:

```
>>> u'á'.encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\xa1'
>>> len(u'á'.encode('utf-8'))
2
```

I can open **IDLE** and I get different results -- not **expected** results, but at least I understand these results.

```
Python 2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  4 2019, 01:37:19) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> 'á'
'\xe1'
>>> len('á')
1
>>> 'à'
'\xe0'
```

The IDLE results are unexpected but I still understand the results;  [Martijn Peters explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034272/python-str-vs-unicode-types#comment26380927_18034277) why `'á'` become `'\xe1'` **in the Latin 1 encoding**.

So why does IDLE give different results from running my Git Bash Python 2.7.1 executable directly? In other words, if IDLE is **using Latin 1** to encoding for my input, **what encoding is used by my Git Bash Python 2.7.1. executable, such that `'á'` becomes `'\xa0'`**

**What I'm wondering**

Is my default encoding the problem? I'm too scared to [change the default encoding.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console#comment36374776_2013263)

```
>>> import sys; sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
```

I feel like it's my *terminal's* encoding that's the problem? (I use git bash) Should I try to [change the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32176732/1175496)?

I try to check [the git bash `locale`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36692549/1175496), the result is:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Also I'm using interactive Python , should I try a file instead, using this?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- sets the source file's encoding, not the output encoding.
```

I know [upgrading to Python 3 is a solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637795/1175496), but I'm still curious about why my Python 2.7.16 behaves differently.

Comment: so, in Python 2, that is interpreted as raw bytes. So it's using whatever encoding your shell is using. If you try using a file with explicitly setting the encoding, you should get what you expect (note, that actually isn't necessary because utf-8 is the default file encoding)

Comment: But yeah, I'm not sure what encoding scheme is interpreting that as byte 160

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you said: "whatever encoding your shell is using" That's what I mean when I say: "I feel like it's my terminal's encoding that's the problem?". I guess I'm curious **how to get or set my terminal's encoding, do you know?**  you said "try using a file with explicitly setting the encodoing", That's what I mean when I say: "should I try a file instead, using this? `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-`", sounds like that would help, but I'm still curious about the terminal/ shell issue...

Comment: Probably the old [IBM code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) from the DOS days.

Comment: @dan04 nice find.

Comment: @NateAnderson definitely try it and report back the results! Also, ignore what I said about the default encoding being utf-8 for the source code, that's definitely true in Python 3, not sure about Python 2. So just set it and let's see

Comment: Thank you both, thanks @dan04 for suggesting **IBM code page 437** -- I realize this question is very narrow (unlikely to be helpful). Also I should clarify it's not just Git Bash, it's a VS Code terminal running Git Bash.... for some reason running Git Bash itself [freezes up when I try to run C:/Python27/python.exe directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36530750/1175496)) OK juanpa.arrivillaga I'll try using a file instead of the interpreter.

Comment: IDLE is a GUI and defaults to the default ANSI code page (Windows-1252 for US and Western European Windows).  The command prompt uses the default OEM code page (cp437 for US Windows and typically cp850 for Western European Windows.  Windows-1252 encodes á as E1 and the OEM code pages use E0.

Comment: Thanks everyone. If someone wants to post the answer to get credit I will accept it. Also I will upvote your comments later (I reached my comment upvote limit today). Otherwise seems like this was just my confusion about an (esoteric?) encoding. I guess one hint is that I was apparently using an encoding where á and à are *not adjacent* (their byte values are quite different! '\xa0' vs '\x85' are far apart, vs '\xe1' and '\xe0' ). And another hint is knowledge about the command prompt/ OEM Codepage, like @MarkTolonen suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @dan04, @MarkTolonen and @  (see the comments to the question above). As @MarkTolonen says:

> command prompt uses the default OEM code page (cp437 for US Windows ....)"

This seems clear from checking [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) for the values I'm trying to encode:

```
>>> 'á' #-> '\xa0' expected in code page 437
>>> 'à' #-> '\x85' expected in code page 437
```

I highlight those values in the screenshot below.
[image: screenshot of code page 437 from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437 highlighting the characters à (mapping to byte \x85) and á (mapping to byte \xa0)]

I used @MarkTolonen's suggestion of running [the `chcp` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp) to get or set the encoding used by my shell/terminal. `chcp` is short for "**ch**ange **c**ode **p**age". If you're using [Git Bash, use `chcp.com`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36174752/1175496) instead. Sure enough, when I run `chcp`, the output is `Active code page: 437`:

[image: a screenshot of two terminals/shells. on the left, git bash, with the command chcp, which returns "bash chcp: command not found". Then the command chcp.com, which returns "Active code page: 437". On the right, cmd, (Windows co mmand line), with the command chcp, which returns "Active code page: 437". Then the command where chcp, which returns "C:\Windows\System32\chcp.com"]

Then I tried @juanpa.arrivillaga's suggestion of using a file. First I tried a file that explicitly used the 437 code page.

1. I added the ["magic comment"](https://peps.python.org/pep-0263/) to specify encoding 437: `# -*- coding: cp437 -*-`, but that's not enough to encode the file. The magic comment [explains to Python how to *decode* the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3170647/1175496).
2. I also had to [change the encoding of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082741/change-the-encoding-of-a-file-in-visual-studio-code) (tell my editor, VS Code, how to *encode* in  CP437).

Once I do both those things with a Python *file* (encode and decode with CP437), I get the **same "unexpected" results as my OP**, which confirms that CP437 is indeed the encoding used by my *terminal/shell*.

[image: screenshot of a text file on the left, edited in Visual Studio Code, saved using "CP437" encoding, and prints the value of 'á' and length of 'á'. On the right the output of running the file in Python 2, which shows the "unexpected" results in the OP, confirming that encoding 437 is the reason for those results.]

In general you must **both** encode **and** include the "decode magic comment", and **make sure your shell uses the same encoding**!

- If I include the cp437 "magic comment" without encoding in CP437 (VS Code default encoding is UTF-8), the length of `'á'` is 2; as in UTF-8! (Note the results are printed in my CP437 shell so they look strange; I see character `├` , which is `\xc3` in CP437!)
- If I encode in CP437 but I don't include the magic comment, I get an error: `(SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xa0' in file 437_encoding.py on line 4)`

[image: screenshot showing the results of encoding in cp437 without the magic comment, and encoding in utf-8 with a cp437 magic comment]

If I encode in utf-8, and I include the "magic comment" for utf-8, and I change my shell  to use utf-8 (`chcp.com 65001`), then I get the results I expect!

[image: screenshot showing a utf8 encoded file with utf8 magic comment in a shell that is changed to use utf8 encoding (code page 65001), then I get the original results I expected in OP]

Finally, if I try @MarkTolonen's suggestion to use `sys.stdout.encoding`, it will tell me the results 'cp437'!

- Please note `sys.stdout.encoding`  (which for me had the value `cp437`)...
- is **not the same** as `sys.getdefaultencoding()` (which for me had the value `ascii`...

[image: screenshot showing a shell, which chcp.com 437 to change the shell's encoding to cp437, then running Python27/python.exe interpreter and printing sys.stdout.encoding (which had cp437 as expected) and sys.getdefaultencoding() (which had ascii, because sys.getdefaultencoding() is not the same as sys.stdout.encoding)]

And if I try to check `sys.stdout.encoding` when I used `chcp.com` to change the code page to UTF-8 (value 65001), I get an error `LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001` which is [described in more detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3259271/1175496)

[image: A screenshot of a git bash terminal, use chcp.com 65001 to change the shell encoding to UTF-8, then run C:/Python27/python.exe, import sys, and get an error "LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001"]

Comment: FYI you can run `chcp` in the command prompt to see the code page used, and can change it as well, e.g. `chcp 1252`

Comment: In Python `import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)` should work in both command prompt and idle.  It may not work in all IDEs as some redirect the output to custom objects that don't support the `encoding` attribute.

Comment: Thanks @MarkTolonen , you're right 1) running `chcp` is helpful to get or set the shell encoding and 2) running `sys.stdout.encoding` is helpful to get the shell encoding (vs what I was using, `sys.getdefaultencoding()`