# How to access the PostgreSQL in Heroku Database as a Service from Windows 10 PC?

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, salesforce, cloud

I installed the PostgreSQL add-on on the server and then in the Heroku CLI I entered the command `heroku pg:psql postgresql-dimensional-16257 --app samar-db` for connecting to the database. But it gave the following outcome.

```
C:\Users\samar>heroku pg:psql postgresql-dimensional-16257 --app samar-db
--> Connecting to postgresql-dimensional-16257
psql (13.2)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.
```

If any further information required for reviewing the problem, I will share them.

Comment: The PostgreSQL version in the server is 13.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a deep search in the StackOverflow community, I found the answer to my question.
[Solution for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48178530/11589463)