# How to change the code page of CLI to work with Vagrant?

Tags: php, windows, vagrant

Everytime I try to run `vagrant up` I get this error:

`` c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/win32/registry.rb:172:in `find': unknown encoding name - CP720 (ArgumentError) ``

I tried to figure out how to change the Code page of the command line to make this work but with no success.

I'm running on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Just type:

```
chcp 1252
```

This command changes terminal's code page. Credit goes to numediaweb(https://stackoverflow.com/a/22861206)