# gulp ruby sass proplem

Tags: ruby, sass, gulp, gulp-ruby-sass

While I was working on gulp this error suddenly appeared

and all tools work ok until I do save in sass file.

```
[16:54:10] Starting 'sass'...
[16:54:10] Finished 'sass' after 44 ms
[16:54:11] C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/registry.rb:72:in `find': unknown encoding name - CP720 (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/registry.rb:72:in `<module:Win32>'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/registry.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/ruby_installer/runtime/msys2_installation.rb:46:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/ruby_installer/runtime/msys2_installation.rb:46:in `iterate_msys_paths'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/ruby_installer/runtime/msys2_installation.rb:69:in `msys_path'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/ruby_installer/runtime/msys2_installation.rb:82:in `mingw_bin_path'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/ruby_installer/runtime/msys2_installation.rb:92:in `enable_dll_search_paths'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/ruby_installer/runtime/singleton.rb:27:in `enable_dll_search_paths'
[16:54:11] from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:1345:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:1345:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `require'
        from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rails4 unknown encoding name - CP720](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815542/rails4-unknown-encoding-name-cp720)

Answer (score 2):

write the following line in the "command promopt with ruby"

```
chcp 1252
```

and it will work :)