# Python UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode when using GEOPY

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, ffmpeg, geolocation

I have been fiddling with python geopy and I tried the basic commands given in the documentation. But I am getting the **UnicodeEncodeError** when trying the `raw` command(to geolocate a query to an address and coordinates)

```
print(location.raw)
```

Error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xa9' in position 83: character maps to <undefined>`

Then I tried the other way around (To find the address corresponding to a set of coordinates)

```
print(location.address)
```

I am getting the same error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0101' in position 10: character maps to <undefined>`

I tried `print((location.address).encode("utf-8"))` , now am not getting any error but the output printed is like this `b'NH39, Mirz\xc4\x81pur`

and when using `print((location.raw).encode("utf-8"))` I am getting error

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on here and what I should do to get a proper output?

**Edit:**(After being marked as duplicate)

[Based on the solution given in this problem I am reporting on how it does not solve my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30540470/5039470)

What I wanted to know is why do I get the UnicodeEncodeError when trying out the basic sample codings given in the documentation and it did answer for that.

If I want to use it an application how do I solve the error and I cannot have the application running on separate IDE or send the output to a external file since my application will function based on the output from geopy, I want the application to run in the terminal as my other applications do.

Comment: Which python version is this? and which os?

Comment: @AnandSKumar Python 3.4 and Windows 7

Comment: Whoever reopened it: there are **two** answers in the original question and [`win_unicode_console` does fix *`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode`*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30551552/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your console is not setup to correctly show the unicode characters that you are trying to print.

In Windows 7, for Python 3.3 + , you can change the code page of python console to 65001 for it to show unicode characters. In terminal run the following -

```
chcp 65001
```

Before starting python/your script.

Comment: If i would like to use it in an application then how can i do it?

Comment: if you do `chcp 65001` once, you should be good to go for any number of times the application is run in that particular command prompt. Otherwise are you asking for a permanent solution to change the code page?

Comment: Yes something like that. Is there a way to automatically do this before that particular script is run?

Comment: You can try the option given here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432545/change-codepage-in-cmd-permanently - for that.

Comment: `chcp 65001` isn't generally a good idea. There are serious bugs in the Windows Console that can result in double-printing or hangs using this code page for all applications using the C standard library IO routines (including Python). Consider: [win_unicode_console](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/win_unicode_console)

Answer (score 0):

```
print json.dumps(address_object.raw,ensure_ascii=False, encoding="utf-8").encode('utf-8')
```

please check, hope this works for you