# install redmine on windows 10 have failed

Tags: ruby, redmine, bitnami, web-platform-installer

> hello there  i'm trying to install redmine on windows 10 ,i have tried to install with bitnami and it have error on
>   installing gems any one will give me a solution on installing redmine
>   on windows 10. i prefer to use iis web server
>
> ,also i have tried "windows web platform installer" with "helicon zoo"
>   and had error on finding file , and i have tried to install it without
>   package manager http://coreboarder.com/blog/?p=465 and it failed on
>   step 4.3 so i skipped but again it failed on step 5.2 when executing
>   "ruby dk.rb install" 
>   i haven't used ruby ever before am i missing something
>   thanks in advance
>
> ps , i have added error snapshot in bellow
>
> [bitnami](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjR4G.png) 
>   [bitnami](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUSLu.png) 
>   [bitnami](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXSe1.png) 
>   [helicontech.com/zoo/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUlCf.png)

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. Bitnami stacks install a large number of files, since they include all dependencies and servers required for running the bundled Web application. If you are installing a Bitnami application on a Windows machine that has an anti-virus agent enabled, this may slow down the installation significantly, and there is also a chance that some servers (Web server or database server) may be blocked by the anti-virus software. In case you continue running into issues, could you please get the log file (bitrock_installer_XXX.log) from the %TEMP% directory?

Comment: thank you i just installed it with Bitnami in another computer with as easy as a few click , but if you are interested in log or the problem causing error i have uploaded it to https://pastebin.com/UcTUz2JY , log had more line than stackoverflow permitting

Comment: today i want to install on our company  server but i get same error

Comment: it seems you ran into an issue with the LOCALE environment variable in the first computer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815542/rails4-unknown-encoding-name-cp720), could you please let us know the region and language configuration of your computer and how the other one (the one where the installer worked) is configured? Thanks

Comment: -`in the computer that worked :`
**format**: 
 _match windows display language_ ,
 _english(united states)_

,**location**: 
 _united states_

`and in the computer that did not worked :`
**format**: 
 _english(united states)_
**location** :
  _iran_ .

another thing that windows defender and firewall was disabled, 
i have searched the forums and some people for resolving `cp700 error` suggested changing the code page `chcp 1252` , then tried to reinstall it , and it failed again , thank you @jotaMartos i appreciate your help

Comment: @nasserfet The problem is `chcp 1252` is only valid for the current terminal session. Some users recommend doing this (but do "chcp 1252" instead of "chcp 437"): https://stackoverflow.com/a/30100565/2670531 After that, restart the computer and run the Redmine installer again. Hope it works!

Comment: hi @marcosbc thank you i have changed my code page (but i used code page 437 )and installed it successfully - happy new year

Answer (score 1):

if you are installing Redmine in your local system which has OS Windows 10, you no need to install all the required set of Softwares separately, you can go and download the Bitnami Redmine [here](https://bitnami.com/stack/redmine/installer)

the download is an installer you can easily install all the software includes Database aswell.

I think this will helps you.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know why you are trying to install redmine the ways you quote usually first check if it is already installed via command prompt and write, gem list.
If not installed, gem install 'redmine' or gem update 'redmine'
I would do a check to see if redmine is actually still an active gem.